# Update Resource on Build dynamically

Tags: c#, compilation, resources

I have a C# application, and I am trying to get embedded resources to update on build with the latest versions of the files.

For example:

- I am embedding some images, and HTML files, that will then later will be utilized within the application. These files are maintained by a different team and could and do change every once in a while. Our core application embeds these files into the application, and when we "Clean" then "Build" it does not grab the latest versions from the file system. But instead keeps the older versions originally inserted into the application.

If I go to the "Resources" page, I can add in new ones, or replace the ones in there with the newer ones manually, and then when I recompile, it will include the newer, manually added versions.

I would like to have Visual Studio to include the latest from the file system on "Build" each time a "Build" is performed.

I cannot figure out how to make that happen, if it is even possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the project's Properties > Build Events, and add lines to the Pre-build event command line field to copy the files from a fixed location (where release versions of the image files are kept and updated by the other team), then have them copied to the project's "Resources" folder. From there, the latest images will be included in the build.

Here is a sample of what to add to the Pre-build event command line:

```
xcopy /Q /Y inputFile outputFile
```

note: UNC paths are supported here